# What causes the distortion of an image when seen through a water droplet?

Tags: optics, refraction, geometric-optics, lenses

I'm trying to explain what causes an image to be distorted when seen through a water droplet.
Specifically, my example is that of a drop of water on a car window. We can see that the image is reversed, which I understand as I take the droplet to act like a planar-convex lens. However, the image is also heavily distorted, it looks pretty curved/rounded, especially near the edges. I'm having issues explaining using sources, formulas, and to overall give a more formal explanation.

Could anyone help? All I can find online is about the magnifying effect of the droplet.
Thank you ! (this is my first post, sorry if I tagged wrong or something like that)

Comment: It's called refraction. The same phenomena your planar-convex lenses use.

Comment: I am a bit rusty with this. But from what I remember, all this stuff with perfect lenses is idealisation. You should already be surprised that you can see anything at all, as different parts of a lens may have different focal distances, which blurs the image. The fact that it is distorted is not a surprise at all. To see what actually happens, you need to consider an actual shape of a drop, carefully take into account refraction angles and see what kind of image is formed.

Comment: @DKNguyen I think the OP understands that part. She is asking about the distortion... which is, of course, explained quantitatively in applied optics textbooks. The challenge is to explain that in a "short" answer. One can model it quite easily with a raytracing program, though... experiment with different shapes and see what it looks like.

Comment: @FlatterMann Ah. Re-reading the question I understand what you mean.

Comment: sounds like an aberration.

Comment: I think you're looking at it backwards - anything that changes the direction of light rays has the potential to distort the image; it's when there's no distortion that's the special case, as it requires the rays to be refracted in a certain way.

Comment: Think about how the picture is built on the retina, point by point. Each point of a non-emmissive, diffuse object bounces light in all directions (well, in a hemisphere); your eye catches a narrow cone (of that hemisphere), and focuses it on your retina. Think of it as of a "pixel". Where it lands depends on the incoming angles, and a droplet changes these angles.

Comment: The curvature of the water drop on a flat surface is not uniformly spherical so there will be distortion of the image especially at the edges where the curvature is the greatest

Comment: @StevanV.Saban Well, even a sphere isn't really the shape you want, I believe. Hence aspherical lenses. A very particular shape without a name as far as I know.

Comment: @DKNguyen You are correct, parabolic shapes give a single focal point and remove spherical aberrations. I have heard of mercury based mirrors where a pool of mercury is placed in the center of a rotating parabolic form to created a smooth parabolic reflecting surface.

Comment: @StevanV.Saban Friggin' magic. I'm not even sure how a rotating device with vibration and imperfect center of rotation is able to beat a ground surface. It's not like a still pool of mercury.

Comment: @DKNguyen I believe the design is a lesser of two evils concept: spherical aberration vs all the mechanical issues you listed. I think it was more of a clever novelty. Since mercury is a noble metal, the oxidation issues with metals like silver also go away.

Comment: @StevanV.Saban yes I think it is that. Sorry to ask again, would you have articles or sources for this? I am having trouble finding relevant information online. Most of what I find is about photography which doesn't explain the subject in a way I am looking for. Thank you so much for your help. I'm not sure how to tag DKNugyen

Comment: @IrisDeSloyd I will try. This was from a book on building telescopes that I read 30 years ago. Try search for mercury telescope mirror.